# Building an installer that runs another installer

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

My company has a project for which I've developed an application in c#. I can create an installer for that application. However, the project requires users to install another application built in c++ that has an installer built using Visual Studio 10. Is there a way that I can build an installer that includes installation of the second product before installing my application?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a bootstrapper or chainer. The WiX Toolset provides this functionality in a tool called [Burn](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/7/14/lets-talk-about-burn). It allows you to provide a single user experience while installing all of your setup packages. You can read about it more in WiX .chm.